# DocuSign pause workflow when creating envelopes from templates c#

Tags: templates, docusignapi

Trying to add workflow step to pause the workflow for approval for second signer.

Please note I was able to add the pause when creating envelopes with recipients added.

But was not able to add the workflow step when trying to create envelope from templates. The templates are created in docusign with only roles added.

Later when creating the envelope through API we added TemplateRoles to add signers against each role.

In this case when we tried to add workflow step to pause the workflow it didn’t pause and sent invitation for the second signer. Can you please help us on this and correct us if we are doing any thing wrong.

Please find the snip of the code below:

```
     var workflowStep = new WorkflowStep()

        {

            Action ="pause_before",

            TriggerOnItem = "routing_order",

            ItemId = "2"

        };



        var workflowsteps = new List<WorkflowStep>();

        workflowsteps.Add(workflowStep);



            TemplateRole signer = new TemplateRole();

        signer.Email = "test@example.com";

        signer.Name = "Test";

        signer.RoleName = "QA";

        signer.RoutingOrder = "1";



            TemplateRole signer1 = new TemplateRole();

        signer1.Email = "test123@example.com";

        signer1.Name = "Test123";

        signer1.RoleName = "RS";

        signer1.RoutingOrder = "2";



     var tempRoles = new List<TemplateRole>();

        tempRoles.Add(signer);

                            tempRoles.Add(signer1);



       EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi(apiclient);

        EnvelopeDefinition envDef = new EnvelopeDefinition();



        envDef.TemplateId = templateId;

        envDef.Status = "Sent";

        envDef.TemplateRoles = tempRoles;



        envDef.Workflow = new Workflow { WorkflowSteps = workflowsteps };



       EnvelopeSummary envelopeSummary = envelopesApi.CreateEnvelope(accountId, envDef);
```

Answer (score 0):

I hesitate to add this because I haven't tested it but I'll mention it in case it unblocks you and see if I can verify later...

I believe if you create the envelope/template with status = paused rather than sent, you should be able to update the template with ARR.

The problem is that when you get to the 'pause' in the above code, it's already 'too late'.

Comment: Thanks for your response.. but for envelope there are only 2 status : sent and created....

Comment: Try stating a more detailed, reproducible answer with code examples / an explanation.